# How to train further in Predict?

Tags: machine-learning

Training further means we can get much smaller loss in the training set,and maybe get the smaller loss in the validation set,so this is useful.

For example

```
p = Predict[ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "BostonHomes"}, "TrainingData"]]
PredictorInformation@p
```

[image]

I want to train further,but find nothing about it in the doc,so trying this

***First method:***

Training more time,no improvement.

```
p = Predict[ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "BostonHomes"}, "TrainingData"],TimeGoal -> 20];
PredictorInformation@p
```

[image]

***Second method:***

Training more data,**big** improvement.

```
p = Predict[Flatten[Table[
                    ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "BostonHomes"},"TrainingData"], 
                         10], 1], PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
PredictorInformation@p
```

[image]

Is any better way to train further in `Predict` that is using training data more times like the `MaxTrainingRounds` do in `NetTrain`?

Comment: Since you use `Predict`, I don't think it can be trained further as the rule..

Comment: In your 2 screenshots you show the ML methods are different so the loss is probably not directly comparable. Also, why do you think that you should train further? (I have never used the ML capabilities of Mathematica, so I don't know how sensible the default behaviour is.)

Comment: @sebhofer I think it can be comparable.Because they are all regression problem.So the loss function will be MSE.

Comment: Doesn't look like MSE to me... I suspect the loss for the GradientBoostedTree is a likelihood value, given that it's so tiny. So I'm still not convinced you can compare them. But again, why do you think that you should train further?

Comment: @sebhofer because I want to control the epoch of training that is common in other framework such as scikit-learn

Comment: @partida Your second method uses a ten-fold duplication of the data. By this procedure you are artificially narrowing the likelihood function (or whatever function is used inside Predict[.]). This may lead to severely overfitted models. Your second method is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe   you are right. I haven't seen anyone use deplicate data to reduce the loss.